# Nginx wordpress subfolder location trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I have WordPress installed inside a sub directory, so site.com/tips-on-something.

For some reason, when accessing the url I get a 404 error. What can I modify to make this work?

```
location ~ /tips-on-something/(.*)$ {

    alias /var/www/some_folder/;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php last;
        break;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass fpm_serv;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

    }
}
```

Comment: `/tips-on-something` is the home of wordpresS?

Comment: no, but it's an example of the folder as it contains hyphens